# Data not inserting into sqlite database

Tags: ios, ios7, sqlite, insert

Hi in my application I have data which want insert into my `sqlite` database .So  I have already created the database successfully, But the problem its not insert data into database.

My database creation code.

```
 - (void)createDatabase
  {

     NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *doctumentsDirectory = [directories lastObject];
     self.databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[doctumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/bp.sqlite"]];

     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   // create DB if it does not already exists
   if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath]) {

       const char *dbPath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &_myDataBase) == SQLITE_OK) {

        char *errorMsg;
        const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS br (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, COST TEXT,QUTY TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_myDataBase, sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK)    {

            [self errorCreatingTable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"failed creating table. ERROR:%s", errorMsg]];
         }

          sqlite3_close(_myDataBase);

      } else {

         [self errorCreatingTable:@"failed openning / creating table"];
      }
   }
 }
```

My insert code i have UIButton action method where i give my insert code.

```
  -(void)aMethod2:(UIButton*)sender
 {

    NSString *inr=[intarr objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",inr);
    NSString *item=[self.menuarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",item);
    NSString *cost=[self.menuarray1 objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",cost);
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO br ('NAME','COST','QUTY') VALUES ('%@','%@','%@')",item,cost,inr];
    NSLog(@"%@",sql);
 }
```

I have used the above code where get the data and inserting into my database but values all passing correctly problem is its not inserting into my database please tell me how to resolve this issue I have been stuck here for long time help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does `aMethod2` access the database?

Comment: @CL. it my uibutton aciton methos

Answer (score 5):

When i saw your question, i couldn't help seeing something that was a bit strange to me... and that was seeing my own code. thanks for using my code snippet from stackoverflow :) [getting error while trying to create sqlite database 'Could not create table' IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303101/getting-error-while-trying-to-create-sqlite-database-could-not-create-table-io/24304174#24304174)

Any way, here is a quick example on how to insert:

```
- (void)insertDictionaryToDataBase:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    if (dictionary) {

        sqlite3_stmt *sql_statement;
        const char *dbPath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &_inboxDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C) VALUES (?,?,?)"];

            const char *insertStatement = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(_inboxDatabase, insertStatement, -1, &sql_statement, NULL);

            sqlite3_bind_text(sql_statement, 1, [dictionary[@"key1"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(sql_statement, 2, [dictionary[@"key2"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(sql_statement, 3, [dictionary[@"key3"] intValue]);


            if (sqlite3_step(sql_statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {

                NSLog(@"sucess!");
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(sql_statement);
            sqlite3_close(_inboxDatabase);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DBmanager.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface DBReadWriteUtil : NSObject

+(sqlite3*)copyDbToDocumentsDirectoryIfNotExist;
+(BOOL)insertData:(NSString*)arg1 cost:(int)arg2 quty:(int)arg3;
+(NSDictionary*)getUploadPendingMedia;
+(int)removeMediaPOStFormId:(int)row_id;
@end
```

DBmanager.m file

```
#import "DBReadWriteUtil.h"

@implementation DBReadWriteUtil

+(sqlite3*)copyDbToDocumentsDirectoryIfNotExist{

    NSString *dbPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]) {
        NSString *localDB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bp" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSError *err;
        if(![fileManager copyItemAtPath:localDB toPath:dbPath error:&err]){
            if (DEBUG_MODE) {
             NSLog(@"SQL: Not ABLE TO COPY FILE -> %@",err);   
            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3 *db_connction;
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db_connction) != SQLITE_OK){
        if (DEBUG_MODE) {
            NSLog(@"SQL : Not ABLE TO CONNECT DB:");
        }
    }
    return db_connction;
}

+(BOOL)insertData:(NSString*)arg1 cost:(int)arg2 quty:(int)arg3{
           BOOL dbStatus = NO;
            sqlite3 *db_connction = [DBReadWriteUtil copyDbToDocumentsDirectoryIfNotExist];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
            const char *query = "insert into br(NAME,cost,quay) values(?,?,?)";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_connction, query, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ){
                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,1,[arg1 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStmt, 2, arg2);
                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStmt,3, arg3,-1);

                NSUInteger err = sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
                if (err != SQLITE_DONE){
                    if(DEBUG_MODE){
                        NSLog(@"error while Inserting image %d %s",err, sqlite3_errmsg(db_connction));
                    }
                }else{
                    dbStatus = YES;
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
            sqlite3_close(db_connction);

            return dbStatus;
        }
```

Call DBmanager

```
BOOL successDB = [DBReadWriteUtil insertData: arg1 cost:arg2 quty:arg3];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
-(void)Insertdata:(NSString*)query{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&_myDataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",query];

        char *errmsg=nil;

        if(sqlite3_exec(_myDataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@".. Inserted ..");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(_myDataBase);
}
```