# issue in inserting large amount of text in sqlite table

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, sqlite

I want to insert text in my sqlite table ,it contains large amount(around 1000 charecters)
Here is my code

//create function

```
    //createdb here
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString  UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytablename(description TEXT)";
        sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
```

//inserting

```
  for (int i=0; i<_generalContentArray.count; i++) 
 {
   char *error;
  if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) 

 {
   NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mytablename(description)    values('%@')",[[_generalContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"description"]];

      const char *insert_stmt=[query UTF8String];
       if (sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error )==SQLITE_OK)
          {
                 NSLog(@"Text added");

          }
        else
          {
                 NSLog(@"Text not added");

          }

                sqlite3_close(database);
   }
 }
```

My problem is it never execute SQLITE_OK statement and always goes to else statement,text is not adding to my table,Please help

Comment: Why are you ignoring `error`? Show it!

Comment: it doesn't shows any error, it just not going to NSLog statement and description field shows empty when i check in my sqlite table

Comment: try to change, description TEXT into description VARCHAR

Comment: yes i tried that but it not works for me

Answer (score 0):

you have to check db is existing or not.try this...

```
for (int i=0; i<_generalContentArray.count; i++)
    {
        char *error;
        //you need to check db is exising or not
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your db name"];
        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)

        {
            NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mytablename(description)    values('%@')",[[_generalContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"description"]];

            const char *insert_stmt=[query UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error )==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Text added");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Text not added");

            }

            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
```

change your query like this...

```
 NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mytablename('description') VALUES('%@')",[[_generalContentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364999/data-not-inserting-into-sqlite-database/24366790#24366790

Comment: my db is exsisting but the text is not showing in description field

Comment: do you have values in _generalContentArray this array?first insert your data,then it will show description field data

Comment: yes it shows values ,my array consists of name and description fields if i insert name it is adding fine to my table but description is not adding

Comment: I printed my query statment it shows the description which i want to insert in my table but it is going to else statement and not adding to my table

Comment: noo i changed that query but it not works again going to else

Comment: change this line      char *insert_stmt=[query UTF8String];
instead of constant and print your query here